# Retrieve parent category name from table in MYSQL results

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MYSQL table called 'categories' from a project I inherited from someone else.

```
id         parent_id       name
1          NULL            Travel
2          NULL            Sleep
3          NULL            Eat
4          NULL            Bath
5          1               Prams
6          1               Travel Systems
7          2               Cots
8          3               High Chairs
```

The table is obviously a lot bigger than that, but you get the general idea. I have a MYSQL statement which brings together this table with other category, brand and product tables, but basically I want to list the parent category name from the above table with the sub-category in the statement. How do I do this?

My current statement is something like:

```
    SELECT brands.name, products.name,  categories.id, categories.name, brands.id, 
FROM `products` , `brands` , `categories`
WHERE products.brand_id = brands.id
AND products.category_id = categories.id
AND brands.name = '$brand'
ORDER BY categories.name, products.name
```

How do I retrieve the parent category names in the results? 
For example if the product is a Pram, how can I output "Travel". I could do seperate MYSQL statements in the loop but I want to avoid this. This is either a stupidly simple question (in which case I apologise for being brain dead) or a little more complicated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know the parent id of the current category and then get the name for that id, you could use a subquery in this way:

```
SELECT name FROM categories WHERE id = (SELECT pid FROM categories WHERE name = $brand)
```

EDIT: Since you need to get the category and subcategory names in the same row for a given subcategory id, try this:

```
SELECT sc.name AS subcategory, c.name AS category
FROM categories sc
LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.id = sc.parent
WHERE sc.id = $subcategory_id
```

Comment: Thanks. We know the parent_id for each product listed and the sub category name. I want to list the parent category for each product listed together with the sub-category. Is there a way I can do a syb query within my query above that retrieves the category name (i.e. getting category.name from category.parent_id = category.id)

Comment: That's a different question then, see my new answer above :-)

Comment: It's quite difficult to explain. The category table has the categories and "sub categories" in the same table. For example the first 4 are "parent categories" (their parent ID is set to NULL) then the rest are "sub categories". So the parent category of "High Chairs" is "Eat" as the parent ID is "3". To be honest I hate the structure of the table as it is making my life difficult!

Comment: I edited my answer and added a new query for getting the subcategory and category name in the same row, let me know if that what you are looking.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me on this one! You've been fab!